# architecture: Services against ManagedBean

Tags: java, ajax, web-services, jsf, ejb

I have been working with JSF like front-end and EJB to Business Model. I ve heard about another kind of architecture, where web services are used instead of EJB and these are called through ajax request. Which is the advantage of using this last Model?

Regards,

Sarang